# Facebook login not working when app in not installed on device but works perfect with Facebook app installed Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to use facebook login in my app when the facebook app is installed i get onSuccess callback and works perfectly. When facebook app is not installed onCancelled is called and the method throws class not found exception even after clicking on continue.

Fragment code

```
binding.llSignInWithFacebook.setOnClickListener {
                if (AppUtil.isNetworkAvailable(requireActivity())) {
                    val i = Intent(requireActivity(), LoginWithFacebook::class.java)
                    startActivityForResult(i, FACEBOOK_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)

//                    performFacebookLogin()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireActivity(),
                        resources.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

        } 


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == FACEBOOK_LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            activity?.finish()
        }
    }
```

LoginWithFacebook

```
private lateinit var loginManager: LoginManager

public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()

    try {
        sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
        loginManager.logOut()
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile, email"))
        setDefaultBehavior()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
    }
}

private fun setDefaultBehavior() {
    callbackManager = create()
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            try {
                updateUI(result)
            } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            }
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            finish()
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            Log.d("MyTag", "Error: ${error.message} ", error)
            Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithFacebook, resources.getString(R.string.connection_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
    })
}
```